# AUTH_USER_MODEL refers to model 'auth_app.AuthAppShopUser' that has not been installed

Tags: python, django, django-models

EDITED: Added more details in the end to help with diagnoses.

I am trying to implement shopify authentication via using this library from github: https://github.com/discolabs/django-shopify-auth

However, after assigning the following value in "settings" and completing other related steps, getting the following error:

AUTH_USER_MODEL refers to model 'auth_app.AuthAppShopUser' that has not been installed

settings.py:

```
    INSTALLED_APPS = [
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
'shopify_auth',
    ]
    AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'auth_app.AuthAppShopUser'
```

auth_demo/models.py:

```
    from django.db import models

    from shopify_auth.models import AbstractShopUser

    class AuthAppShopUser(AbstractShopUser):
        pass
```

screenshot of my vscode: take.ms/gB0pD – codingbat2050
entire code from settings.py - pastebin.com/ju2kjTFe

Comment: You haven't added `auth_app` to `INSTALLED_APPS`... Also you say the model is in `auth_demo/models.py`? Then the setting should be `AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'auth_demo.AuthAppShopUser'`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your screenshot, It seems you did not update the name of the app you created in your settings.py file.
Can you check that as well?

Answer (score 0):

try to run migrations with:

```
python manage.py migrate
```

If it doesn't solve your problem, can you please share the whole settings.py file?

Comment: It is the same error as I have mentioned on running migrate command. Here is the settings.py file:  https://pastebin.com/ju2kjTFe

Answer (score 0):

You don't have a module called "auth_app", it's "auth_demo", you need to change AUTH_USER_MODEL to reference the correct name of your module.

```py
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'auth_demo.AuthAppShopUser'
```

Comment: Still not working. For reference - django project name is "auth_demo". I created a new app inside it called "auth_app". This screenshot shows everything I believe along with error: https://take.ms/gB0pD